# cakephp : Sort ASC but with 0 value at end

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In a find request, how can I sort numeric value in ascending order but having the 0 value at end ?

I want : [2,5,7,7,0,0]

```
$this->Resuls->find()
  ->order(['Resuls.sec'=>'asc']);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the DBMS there's various ways to achieve this.

A way that should work on all DBMS supported by CakePHP would probably be to use  a `CASE` statement to first order the rows where `Resuls.sec` is `0` to the back, and after that order ascending by `Resuls.sec` regulary, that should get you the results that you are looking for.

```
$query = $this->Resuls->find();

$zeroLastCase = $query->newExpr()->addCase(
    [$query->newExpr()->add(['Resuls.sec' => 0])],
    [1, 0],
    ['integer', 'integer']
);

$query
    ->orderAsc($zeroLastCase)
    ->orderAsc('Resuls.sec');
```

That would generate an `ORDER BY` clause similar to:

```sql
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Resuls.sec = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, 
    Resuls.sec ASC
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Case statements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::order()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_order)**

Comment: Very nice. What does the `newExpr()->add()` function do? What is it adding?

Comment: @cgTag It adds the conditions to the `QueryExpression` object that is returned by `newExpr()`.

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm!   I learned something today ;-)